# Unicode escape sequences vs hexadecimal values

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, hex, widechar

To encode Unicode/UTF-8 characters in my program, I've been using the `\uXXXX` escape sequences, such as:

```
wchar_t superscript_4 = L'\u2074';  // U+2074 SUPERSCRIPT 4 '⁴'
wchar_t subscript_4   = L'\u2084';  // U+2084 SUBSCRIPT 4 '₄'
```

However, using hexadecimal should work just fine, since Unicode is encoded in hexadecimal.

```
wchar_t superscript_4 = 0x2074;
wchar_t subscript_4   = 0x2084;
```

Will the second example encode the character properly? Will I run into wide-char issues, segmentation faults, or incorrectly stored character values? If so, why? If not, why?

Comment: The first examples define a character literal with a value larger than CHAR_MAX as far as I know. That's bad all in itself...

Comment: Have you tried `L'\u2074'` instead of `'\u2074'`?

Comment: @rubenvb whoops, had a typo. Fixed (per Keine's comment).

Comment: @PeterJ Multi-char characters are implementation defined and endian dependent

Comment: @KeineLust They *might* be endian dependent, but they are implementation-defined and an implementation could define them as using a particular endianness independent of whatever’s used in execution.

Comment: Yes, thats what I say :) @DanielH it was an answer for a deleted comment of PeterJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* initialize them with hex constants, but you could also initialize normal `char`s with numeric constants, e.g. `char c = 67;`.  It works the same way; it assigns whatever `char` or `wchar_t` has the value of that `int`. In the example you give, and assuming a Unicode execution environment (not quite guaranteed but highly probable) it’s subscript or superscript 4; in my example it’s a capital `C`.

[In particular](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/character_constant), for regular `char`s, technically character constants like `'C'` have type `int`, and you are usually assigning `int` values to `char`s. For `wchar_t`s, the constants do actually have `wchar_t` type, and the integral value is the same value you’d get by calling [`mbtowc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbtowc). So assuming you’re working in a Unicode environment, the hex constants are equivalent to the Unicode escapes.

Usually you don’t want to do this, though; using character literals makes it clearer what your intention is. This is especially true if you use non-ASCII characters in your source code, in which case you can make the code just be

```
wchar_t superscript_4 = L'⁴'
wchar_t subscript_4   = L'₄'
```

Also note that for many purposes it’s better to use `char16_t` or `char32_t`, because `wchar_t` can have different widths on different platforms; it might also be cleaner to just use UTF-8 until you have a specific need to switch to something else.

Comment: So initializing them with hex constants *does* do the same thing? (I read your answer and I agree with the second sentence, I'm just curious.)

Comment: @MDXF It does, assuming that the execution environment is Unicode. In theory the execution environment could use some multibyte non-Unicode character set, in which case the Unicode escapes would still work (if the execution character set has the right characters), but the hex constants would not; in practice the execution environment will be Unicode and this won’t be an issue.